# Included Library vs. Placeholder Template in CoDeSys

Tags: plc, st, codesys

What is the difference between including a library in a CoDeSys project and including a placeholder template? And why can't certain libraries be added as libraries as opposed to placeholder templates? For example, I can't seem to add the Standard Library (System) as a library, only a placeholder template.

In the image below the CCAux library is added as a library where as the CmpApp library is a placeholder. If you open the 'placeholders' tab you do not see the CCAux library in there but you will find the CmpApp. What is the difference between these two?

[image: Libraries]

[image: placeholders]

Comment: I cannot get your question. How is that related? Libraries you add in library manager, placeholders in visualization. Those are completely different entities.

Comment: @SergeyRomanov It would appear you did understand my question a bit. It turns out I didn't know enough to know my question wasn't specific. I added some images and a more specific question to the post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Placeholders are not realy an library element, but can be used to personalize Your library as You can associate them to a library element and apoint what version of the library is to be used to resolv that Placeholder.
A better explanation can be found on this link:

https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/27021601953748491.html&id=

The document has images that can help You undestand.
There are more information in subfolders appointed by the link above.